# CPU usage graphs on Azure Container Instance

Tags: docker, azure-container-instances

When running a simple Linux container on ACI there is a huge discrepancy between the 'graphed' CPU usage in the portal compared to running 'top' in the container itself.

I can see my process running in 'top' and the cpu usage stays at around 5% and the load on the machine is below 0.10 but the portal reports around 60% usage.  It's a single processor container.

Under heavier loads I have seen CPU usage of 300-400 % which feels like an issue related to the number of processors but even this does not add up and as previously stated it's a single processor container

Any thoughts ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the ACI CPU Usage metrics seems to be in millicores, not in %. So when you see 300-400 it would be in fact .3 to .4 CPU which for a single CPU would represent 30-40%.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-monitor#available-metrics

Hoping this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @djsly , very much appreciated.  I had started to realise last night that it was out by a factor of 10 on my single core test instance.  For sure I should have dug deeper into the documentation but there is so much of it sometimes!  A small 'label' to that effect on the graph would be a huge pointer in the right direction. Thanks again